# jQuery div flip animation on click with CSS and SASS not flipping correctly

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I searched a few similar questions but couldn't find a solution to my problem, so here it is.

I'm trying to just create a simple flip box.

1. Press the Box and flips to the back side.
2. Press the box again and flips back to the front side.

My issue is that the flip looks bad, and once it flips to the back side, the flip card will not flip back to the front. I'm just starting to learn SASS and I'm making this flip card to gain some experience using SASS mixins.  I will be cleaning it up once I get it working.

Here is my current code.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="flip3D">
      <div class="front">Front Box</div>
      <div class="back">Back Box</div>
 </div>
```

CSS (SASS):

```
@mixin flipCard($width, $height, $color) {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  //display: block;
  //display: inline-block;
  float: left;

  .front {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
    background: $color;
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;    
    //z-index: 1002; 
  }

  .back {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
    background: $color - 40;
    width: $width;
    height: $height;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
    transition: transform .5s linear 0s;    
    //z-index:1002;
  } 
}

.flip3D {
  @include flipCard(240px, 200px, white - 20);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip3D").on('click', function() {
    if($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
        frontFlip();
    } else {
        $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
        backFlip();
    }
  });
});

function frontFlip() {
    $(".front")
    .css('transform', 'perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg)')
    .css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg)')
 }

function backFlip() {
    $(".back")
    .css('transform', 'perspective(600px) rotateY(0)')
    .css('-webkit-transform', 'perspective(600px) rotateY(0)')
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While trying to create a flip effect with both the front and back elements rotating, you should always rotate both the elements for every flip action.

The direction of the flip (or the rotation angle) depends on whether the back or the front is clicked.

- To bring the `.back` element into view, the `.back` should be rotated to 0deg and `.front` should be rotated to -180deg.
- To bring the `.front` element into view, the `.front` should be rotated to 0 deg and `.back` should be rotated to 180deg.  Note how the signage of the angles are different for the rotation. This is due to the fact that the `.front` has to rotate clockwise when the `.back` needs to come into view and the `.back` has to rotate in counterclockwise direction when `.front` needs to come into view.

**Note:** I have removed the prefixed properties to keep the code simple and added prefix free library.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".flip3D").on('click', function() {

    if ($(this).attr('data-click-state') == 1) {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 0)
      frontFlip();
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-click-state', 1)
      backFlip();
    }
  });

});

function frontFlip() {
  $(".front")
    .css('transform', 'perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg)')
  $(".back")
    .css('transform', 'perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg)')
}

function backFlip() {
  $(".back")
    .css('transform', 'perspective(600px) rotateY(0)')
  $(".front")
    .css('transform', 'perspective(600px) rotateY(-180deg)')
}
```

```css
.flip3D .front {
  position: absolute;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(0deg);
  background: sandybrown;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3D .back {
  position: absolute;
  transform: perspective(600px) rotateY(180deg);
  background: aqua;
  width: 240px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform .5s linear 0s;
}
.flip3D {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip3D">
  <div class="front">Front Box</div>
  <div class="back">Back Box</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome - thank you for the quick reply and answer.  I'll mark this as the answer once the time limit lets me.  The console.log(1) is just for testing right?

Comment: @user3622460 Yep, I have removed it :) Glad that it helped you.